# How to not change CWD in NerdTree when open file node?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How do I prevent NERDTree from changing the CWD when I open a file node?

I usually open a project folder with

```
cd apps/project
vim .
```

I want NERDTree's current working directory to be fixed with (apps/project) when i open a file node.

I tried `:let NERDTreeChDirMode=0`, but it does not work.

Comment: Are you setting `autochdir` in your vimrc?

Comment: no , i use this vim config files(vim.spf13.com) and set noautochdir does not work too

Comment: Can you describe how did you open a file node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let NERDTreeChDirMode=0` should be put in your ~/.vimrc.local for the spf13 vim plugin distribution, not executed after the fact. Also make sure that `acd` or `autochdir` is not in your ~/.vimrc.local.

Comment: thanks , i've figured it out . let NERDTreeChDirMode=0 and set noautochdir should works . but i also need to comment this out (autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^\[A-Za-z0-9\]*://" | lcd %:p:h | endif) . i use this vim configuration(https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc)

Comment: I have resolved similar issue but I had to additionally remove ~/.vimviews/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this properly, on a new install, for example, is to set the `g_spf13_no_autochdir` to 1, on `.vimrc.before.local` (sets the toggle before all of spf13 is loaded)

```
echo let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1 >> .vimrc.before.local
```

This will let you customize NERDTree behaviour without modifying spf13's config.